# Postgresql date subtract

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

How can I make a valid request like:

```
UPDATE b2c SET tranche = '18 - 25'
WHERE (dateofbirth::date BETWEEN NOW()::date - 18 'year' AND NOW()::date - 25 'year')
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dateofbirth::date BETWEEN 
    (NOW() - interval '25 year')::date AND 
    (NOW() - interval '18 year')::date
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have 'nothink update', however I have in 'dateofbirth' some date like 1995-08-04, 1994-08-07, 1993-11-11...

Comment: sorry, I just had to switch 25 year with 18 year... I didn't know order of BETWEEN argument have an importance...

Comment: @Macbernie Fixed. The dates were inverted. It is the oldest first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgres cast syntax:

```
UPDATE b2c SET tranche = '18 - 25'
WHERE dateofbirth::date BETWEEN 
    NOW()::date - '25y'::interval AND 
    NOW()::date - '18y'::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) and [`Age()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

```
select EXTRACT(year FROM age('1995-08-04'::date))::int age
```

Output:

```
age
integer
--------
      20
```

So you can write *where* condition like below

```
UPDATE b2c SET tranche = '18 - 25'
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM age(dateofbirth))::int >=18 
 AND  EXTRACT(year FROM age(dateofbirth))::int <=25
```